# Dynamically load scripts and render widget in each angular component created with ng-for

Tags: angular, typescript, tradingview-api

I am setting up a angular 7 webapplication and want to render a TradingView-widget in each component in a list of 25 components created with ng-for.

I am loading the external js-script dynamically like it is shown here: https://medium.com/@zainzafar/angular-load-external-javascript-file-dynamically-3d14dde815cb

The script-loader-service is in the constructor of each component and loads the script in its ngOnInit()

The service for loading the scripts runs the request for all 25 components. But the widget is only rendered in the first component of my list.

Here is a stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ud479?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @trichetriche  i added an example on stackblitz

Comment: Well you manipulate the DOM yourself, this is an issue already. Are you sure this is the good practice when it comes to that library ?

Comment: I am not sure if Iunderstand your commment but no its probably not a good practice. I tried to wrap my components into a ng-container and ng-template. I think the ngFor is creating the ng-template now and not a real DOM-object.
i updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ud479?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Angular had its own way of handling Dom manipulation, and doing it yourself is definitely not it. Have you looked around for another solution?

Comment: Sorry, what is my problem here? Where in my code is a Dom manipulation that is not ok? Thats what i found in serveral tutorials, but its also now working with my widget. Is this considered an OK way? 
<li *ngFor="let item of list">
  <widget ></widget>
</li>

Comment: You use appenchChild to add scripts if I remember correctly (I'm on phone), this might be the caque of your issue, as your code is not running in NgZone. I'm totally not sure about it though, I'm merely offering ideas to resolve your issue !